# how to pass and modify v-model to the vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I'm trying to pass as a prop attribute some input fields and emit it to the parent component, but can't edit the input fields. I'm passing props down as a titled v-model to the child component. I think I'm wrong with the logic and reading correctly the docs, just can't get it. When I'm typing the input nothing remains in the input field.

```
function fullname() {
  return {
    fullname: {
      firstname: 'Adam',
      lastname: 'Coll'
    }
  }
}
export { fullname }
```

**Parent component**

```
<template>
  <Child
    v-model:windDirectionDep="names.fullname.firstname"
    v-model:windDirectionArr="names.fullname.lastname"/>
</template>

<script>
   import { name as setName } from '../'
    
   data () {
    return {
      names: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setName () {
      this.names = setName()
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.setName()
  },
</script>
```

**Child component**

```
<template>
  <q-input
    name="firstname"
    :value="windDirectionDep"
    @update:model-value="(value) => emit('update:windDirectionDep', value)" />
  
  <q-input
    name="lastname"
    :value="windDirectionArr"
    @update:model-value="$emit('update:windDirectionArr', $event)" />
  </q-input>
        
</template>

<script>
  props: [
    'windDirectionDep',
    'windDirectionArr'
  ],
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Quasar `<q-input>` component is *not* the same as the native HTML `<input>` and should not be assumed to emit the same events.

If you check the [q-input API](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input#qinput-api) under the "Events" tab you can see all the events you can listen to.  The one you want is `@update:model-value`.  The model value will also not be on `$event.target.value` but will just be `$event`.

Your q-input should then look something like:

```html
<q-input
  name="firstname"
  :model-value="windDirectionDep"
  @update:model-value="$emit('update:windDirectionDep', $event)">
</q-input>
```

Comment: This answer seems to be correct and conforming to the documentation, but the inputs still don't get any changes though. I've edited the initial code BTW

Comment: My mistake.  The docs also specify under "Props" tab -> "Model" section that the model value prop name is `model-value`, and **not** `value`.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Instead of using `:value` and `@update:model-value` you can use `computed` way as explained [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#v-model-arguments)

```
//Parent

<template>
<Child
    v-model:wind-direction-dep="names.fullname.firstname"
    v-model:wind-direction-arr="names.fullname.lastname"/>
</template>

<script>
   import { name as setName } from '../'
    
   data () {
    return {
      names: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setName () {
      this.names = setName()
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.setName()
  },
</script>
```

Note that I used pascal-case (`wind-direction-dep` and `wind-direction-arr`) for v-model arguments

```
//Child
<template>
  <q-input
    name="firstname"
    v-model="windDirectionDepModel"
    />
  
  <q-input
    name="lastname"
    v-model="windDirectionArrModel"
    />
        
</template>

<script setup>
  import { computed } from 'vue';
  const props = defineProps([
    'windDirectionDep',
    'windDirectionArr'
  ]) 
  const emit = defineEmits([
    'update:windDirectionDep'
    'update:windDirectionArr'
  ])
  const windDirectionDepModel = computed({
    get: function() {
      return props.windDirectionDep
    },
    set: function(val) {
      emit('update:windDirectionDep',val)
    }
  })
  const windDirectionArrModel = computed({
    get: function() {
      return props.windDirectionArr
    },
    set: function(val) {
      emit('update:windDirectionArr',val)
    }
  })
</script>
```